# jQuery setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'd like to add a timeout to this tooltip code so it only displays if the mouse hovers over it after a while rather than immediately... I tried adding the `setTimeout()` but I could not figure out how to use the `clearTimeout()` so the tooltip does not hide on mouseout. Can you help?

```
// -----------------------------------------------
// TOOLTIP MOUSE HOVER
// -----------------------------------------------
function mcTooltip() {
    $('.mcTxb').mousemove(function(e) {
        var mcHoverText = $(this).attr('alt');
        var mcTooltip = $('.mcTooltip');
        $(mcTooltip).text(mcHoverText).show('fast');
        $(mcTooltip).css('top', e.clientY + 10).css('left', e.clientX + 10);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        var mcTooltip = $('.mcTooltip');
        $(mcTooltip).hide('fast');
    });
}
mcTooltip();
```

I tried this:

```
    // -----------------------------------------------
// TOOLTIP MOUSE HOVER
// -----------------------------------------------
function mcTooltip() {
    $('.mcTxb').mousemove(function(e) {
        var mcHoverText = $(this).attr('alt');
        var mcTooltip = $('.mcTooltip');
        setTimeOut(function(){
            $(mcTooltip).text(mcHoverText).show('fast');
        }, 300);
        $(mcTooltip).css('top', e.clientY + 10).css('left', e.clientX + 10);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        var mcTooltip = $('.mcTooltip');
        $(mcTooltip).hide('fast');
    });
}
mcTooltip();
```

Comment: Why not just remove the "mouseout" callback?

Comment: Show us your attempt at using `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you're using animation, you can use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to defer the appearance of your tooltip:

```
$(mcTooltip).text(mcHoverText).delay(1000).show('fast');
```

In your `mouseout` function, use [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to cancel any existing delays or animations, and then hide the tooltip:

```
$(mcTooltip).stop(true).hide('fast');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var my_timer;
$('.mcTxb').hover(
    function () {
        my_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            //do work here
        }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        clearTimeout(my_timer);
    }
);
```

This will wait half a second before doing *whatever* when you `mouseover` the element and the *whatever* will not happen if you `mouseout` within the half second.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `hover()` instead, it's less code (and that's always good, IMO).

Like so:

```
function mcToolTip() {
    $(".mcTxb").hover(function(){
        // mouseover stuff here
        $("element").delay(3000).show(); // 3 second delay, then show
    }, function(){
        // mouseout stuff here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I thought I answer it for others. The main reason the timeout was not working was the case of "setTimeOut" . You cant camel hump the Out part. Its "setTimeout".

Answer (score 0):

***setTimeout*** is does not work on mouseover or hover. It is safe to use .delay().

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(mcTooltip).text(mcHoverText).show('fast');
}, 300);

// use this instead.

$(mcTooltip).text(mcHoverText).delay(3000).show('fast');
```